# Migrating from PyCharm to VS Code: setting paths

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm

I want to switch over to VS Code. I did the following to enable python with the packages I typically use, including a local utilities package on this machine:

- Searched for the setting `python.pythonPath` and made it PycharmProjects/Project/venv/Scripts/python.exe for both this workspace and for my user
- Changed my Windows user PYTHONPATH to PycharmProjects/Project/venv/Scripts/python.exe
- Tried PycharmProjects/python.exe;local-utilities-directory

However, the folder I'm trying to manually set won't show up as a possible option when I click on my interpreter in the bottom right. Instead I'm defaulting to an older interpreter that doesn't have all the packages I've amassed.

While I can access some packages, while trying to pull in my personal utilities library, `pip` fails (the term pip is not recognized...)

I see that there are a few other ways to change the python path, however, to my understanding, whether you do it in a .json or via the IDE UI, shouldn't actually matter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I messed things up by offering too many paths.

I had to double check that the exact same path showed up first in:

- Work setting pythonPath
- User setting pythonPath
- Windows profile path
- Windows profile PYTHONPATH

I deleted the other "backup" paths, and it ended up working.